# Call 2 different ReactiveMongoRepository under the same spring transaction using @Transactional

Tags: java, transactions, reactive-programming, project-reactor, spring-data-mongodb-reactive

Let's have 2 different `ReactiveMongoRepository` mongo repositories:

```
@Autowired
private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;

@Autowired
private CurrencyArchiveRepository currencyArchiveRepository;
```

And a @Transactional method which call both repositories, chainning their callings in a reactive way:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public Mono<Void> delete(final String currencyCode) {
  final CurrencyArchive currencyArchive = buildCurrencyArchive();

  return this.currencyArchiveRepository.save(currencyArchive)
      .flatMap(c -> this.currencyRepository.delete(c.getCode()))
      .then();
}
```

What I want to achieve is executing the 2 repository calls under the same transaction, so that, for instance, if the `.delete(...)` invocation fails, do the previous `.save(...)` rollback out of the box.
I did different tests and I couldn't find a way to get it working so far.

I don't know if this is even posible in a reactive way, as long as when the execution jumps into the flatmap block the `TransactionAspectSupport` seems to be lost (checked it with the debugger).

Could you give me some advices of how this could be achieved?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Mongo transactions are disabled by default. You have to register `ReactiveMongoTransactionManager` in a config class to enable it.

```
@Bean
ReactiveMongoTransactionManager transactionManager(ReactiveDatabaseFactory factory){  
    return new ReactiveMongoTransactionManager(factory);
}
```

After this it should be work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already have ReactiveMongoTransactionManager added exaclty as you suggest and it does not work either.